# Declaring a private boolean causes build crash

Tags: java, ant

I have a Java project that builds using Apache Ant to a website.  This is not my code I am trying to learn and modify it.  When I alter an object that implements Serializable, and is  extended by other objects in a very small way, such as declaring a private boolean the server is unable to load the site.

ERROR - RequestCycle               - Can't instantiate page using constructor public foo.bar.exportconfiguration.ExportConfigurationList()

Any ideas on where to look for answers? Looking for advice or ideas.

I know this is kind of vague, I'll check back and add more details if I can find them. Doing searches on another boolean variable to try to replicate any checking, or verifying behavior that applies to it.

Edit: To clarify, I am only declaring the boolean:

private boolean fooBarFlag;

The boolean is never used.

Thanks

Comment: As you say, its a little vague. Can you describe what you mean by 'parent' object? Can you describe what is crashing and how? Can you provide any stack traces or error logging you may have?

Comment: "The whole thing crashes" tells us **nothing**. Does the compilation step fail with some error? Does the build bail because some Tests fail? Does the code get deployed and produce strange results when executed?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I've done my best to clarify some more

Comment: Can you describe the build and deploy process? Are the subclasses in the same project as the superclass that you are modifying? i.e. are you rebuilding the subclasses when you build the modified superclass? Are you hot deploying to your app server? Which app server are you using? When does the error occur? e.g. on server startup, on page access, when you hot deploy?

Comment: The superclass and subclasses are in the same project, they are built to .Jar file that is manually copied into another project and then deployed using Apache Ant.   The deployment is done to a dev server where testing happens.  Apache Server.  The error occurs on page access and was extracted by viewing server logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The boolean is never used.

This is normally just a warning, however, I don't know if the build script is set up to fail on warnings.

Try and add `@SuppressWarnings ( "unused" )` to the declaration:

```
@SuppressWarnings ( "unused" )
private boolean fooBarFlag;
```

Comment: Another possible reason is if the class is `Serializable` and needs to be backwards compatible: then adding a simple unused field can break the code.

Comment: It is Serializable, I'm now researching Serializable classes and how to implement them, thanks for the tip.

Comment: It ended up being caused due to the Serializable class, I just have to manually change the serialVersionUID to evolve the class.  Thanks for the help!